# Liskov principle: subclasses can have stronger invariants. How could it work?

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, solid, liskov-substitution

Learning about the Liskov principle, I do understand that preconditions can be weakened and postconditions can be stronger in subtypes. However, I do not understand how invariants can be stronger in the subtype?
 If the base class says e.g. the Speed must be lower than 100 al the time, and then a subtype says Speed < 50, replacing the base with the subtype can cause some issues, or not? I mean, if somewhere the code works with the base class and works the speed of 90, introducing the subtype means it will be invalid.

Code and some text can be found in the slides 15=16:

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aldrich/214/slides/formal-analysis-part2.pdf

Comment: Is speed an input or an output in your exampe?

Comment: @JacobRaihle It is the invariant of the class.

Comment: Never use inheritance to set a scalar value like a maximum speed. If you must extend a class, use it to extend the behaviour, not modify a number.

Comment: But where is speed coming from? Is it provided, and the type promises to accept values up to 100, or does the type accept other input and promise a behavior based on a speed no greater than 100? I am getting mixed messages from your question and comments here.

Comment: @MrCochese *"Never use inheritance to..."* Why? What if the scalar value is used by one or multiple extended behaviors?

Comment: @guillaume31 That's kind of irrelevant. The maximum speed is still logically a property of the base class, whether extended behaviours use it or not. If you extend a class purely to change a number, you're tying yourself in knots.

Comment: I'm not saying "purely to change a number". Example: the subclass defines different acceleration behavior _and_ sets a different max speed related to it. I'm careful about dry "never do X" claims. Your first statement could be understood as "never redefine a scalar value in a subclass under any circumstance" and you didn't explain exactly why.

Comment: @guillaume31 (digress) A better way to say this is a refactor: "Convert hard-coded numerical constraints from types (classes) into objects in the form of business rules". A refactor is a choice which you can apply in either direction. Converting the numerical constraint means creating an instance of a business rule object where the numerical constraint is part of the instantiation. Different instances can be instantiated with different numerical values. The rationale behind this is to avoid using the strong typing system to enforce things that are not worth the consequences from strong typing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liskov Substitution Principle states that you can replace implementation of class T without altering any of the desirable properties of T.  In your example you mention a base class where the Speed must always be lower than 100 and in an implementation, the Speed must always be lower than 50.

This isn't a violation because the base class only requires that speed be lower than 100 and that is presumably met regardless of if your derived class requires it to be lower than 50 or if it requires it to be lower than 75.

In other words if speed is lower than 50, it must also therefore be lower than 100 and so there is no violation.  The violation would be if your derived class allowed speed to exceed 100.

Replacing one instance where speed is lower than 100 with another that allows speed to be over 200 would result in breaking Liskov Substitution Principle as well as the laws of the road!

Comment: I am still thinking about the implementation - when I have a code working with the base class, let's assume it provides such values that the invariant is 90. Now I replace the base class with the subclass and keep the rest unchanged...and 90 is not acceptable anymore.

Comment: @EzoelaVacca The 90 would be the conditions of the base class.  If that is violated, even indirectly, then it no longer can be substituted without potentially undesireable side effects.  Not sure I understand where you're coming from.

Comment: As it is the invariant, let's say it is calculated based on some constructor parameters, like X*Y. So you pass 10 and 9 to the base class object constructor, so its invariant is 90, that is correct. Now you replace the base class with its subclass, and 90 becomes invalid because the invariant should be less than 50.

Comment: Well, in that case, you can't say that an invariant is defined in terms of a specific number (because it has to apply to the whole type, i.e. not just to a specific instance, but to *every* instance), but you can say that the invariant is that the speed is lower than X*Y. Note that when the subtype is instantiated, you have to provide these parameters as well.

Comment: @EzoelaVacca If the derived class states that the values X\*Y must be less than 50 and X*Y (due to values in the base class) end up being 90, your implementation is violating its own prerequisite.  Liskov Substitution Principle only says that whereever you use the base class, you use an implementation that guarantees speed is less than 90.  If the implementation doesn't meet its own prerequisite of less than 50, this isn't a violation of Liskov.  It's a separate issue.

Comment: @Neil Oh, I think I got it - I thought that the principle says that you need to be able substitute the derived class for the base class anytime and anywhere and it must work correctly. But in that case, polymorphism would not work either.

Comment: @Neil As for my example, I meant that the method call using X,Y values would be working for the base class object, but not for the derived one. And I originally thought Liskov dictates that this should work too.

Comment: @EzoelaVacca: Note, however, that if the base class defines the max speed to be XY, then, if you just look at the implementation, the invariant *isn't* that the speed is < 90, because the value of max speed *varies across instances*. OTOH, if you start by asserting that the "< 90" is an invariant, then the implementation is incorrect. For this to be an invariant, It's not enough just to be able to create an instance that satisfies it - you should not be able to even construct an instance that violates it, or to make any runtime state changes that would result in an observable violation.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Right, but I think it can vary as long as the condition < 90 holds, correct? In reality, I surely thinks there would need to be a validation to be sure that the invariant is not violated.

Comment: @EzoelaVacca: Yes, yes, of course - you can have a parameterized constructor, as long as you also have some mechanism to enforce the overall invariant (so that the variation is within the limits of the < 90 condition, which is itself invariant across instances). E.g., you can perform a check and throw an exception if < 90 is violated. Also, depending on what the exact condition is, and the programming language you use, you may in some cases be able to enforce the invariant in other ways, like through the type system (e.g. using an unsigned type if the number must be nonnegative, etc.)

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Thanks. I think now I understand that. Basically, the subtype needs to ensure at least the same as the basetype (<50 is still compliant with less < 100). So any code that relies on the basetype invariant will be satisfied even with the subclass instance.

Answer (score 2):

Liskov substitutability does *not* mean that you can substitute an object of a subclass for an object of a superclass *and your program will still be correct*. The only thing it guarantees is that *promises made by the superclass will be honored by all subclasses*.

In your case, the superclass promised "My speed will not exceed 100", and it keeps that promise. The subclass also keeps this promise.

The subclass also introduces a new, stricter promise: "*My* speed will not exceed 50", and it honors this promise as well. This is possible because the states allowed by the new premise are a strict subset of the states allowed by the old promise.

The superclass doesn't honor this new promise, in fact it doesn't even know about it. That means that its behaviour will be different from the behaviour of the subclass. Obviously, this can affect program correctness - substitutability does *not* mean that any of the classes in a class hierarchy is as good as the other.

Then what good is Liskov substitutability? It's only as good as the type system in your language. It does a good job enforcing pre- and postconditions that the type system in your language can express. For instance, once you declare a method that returns an `unsigned int`, you can be sure that it will never return a negative value, *and neither will any subclass*. But you probably cannot express "this method finds the best nearest-neighbour classification of the input values" in the type system, therefore the LSP cannot guarantee program correctness under inheritance. (To be fair, almost no formalism can.)

Comment: Actually, the definition does say that - that the behavior, correctness (and that is explicitly mentioned) does not change.

Comment: @EzoelaVacca The definition says that correctness **according to the pre- and postconditions** does not change. But that is not all there is to correctness of a program. If it were, we could just interpret the pre- and postconditions and leave out the programming language altogether.

Comment: No, it says that objects of type T can be replaced with objects of type S without altering any of desirable properties, such as correctness. More popular definition reads that "You can use a child object anywhere where its parent is used, without introducing errors".

Comment: @EzoelaVacca: You are using subtly different definitions of "correctness" here. Substituting a subtype, as defined by LSP, does mean that the program will (in a perfect world) remain technically correct, in a sense that it will behave in conformance to a specification of the (base) type. But in a more general, more informal sense, it will not necessarily *do* what its human users intended.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Check the other answer, which is correct. The condition lower than 100 remains correct even in the subtype, because lower than 50 is a "sub-set".

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Reading the Liskov's paper, actually she does say that the behavior must be as expected, which is also why it mentiones "behaviorally substitutable".

Comment: @EzoelaVacca: Yes it is very much about the expected behavior (I'm assuming you are referring to the paper "A Behavioral Notion of Subtyping" by Liskov and Wing). The authors use this notion as a starting point to define what it means for something to be a subtype of another type. 

The second part of my comment was about what I thought Kilian Foth was talking about. E.g., you may implement an algorithm or a formula incorrectly (so that your users get bad results), but remain within the limits imposed by the supertype and not violate LSP. But that's a different kind of correctness.